# Does read_only permission allow file modifications using TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I gave an account the read_only permission through team project portal, so the account can read the share document through web access, but can't modify the files.  However, when the account is logged in to TFS through vs2010, there is some problem; the share document can be modified! Who can tell me why?

Comment: Is the account in another group that has more than read_only permissions?

Comment: No, I check it agin, the account is only in read_only group.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if that account is added in another group and that group has rights to modify files.

Comment: The account is only in read_only group, and when it access share document through web, it perform normally.

Comment: if it has readonly rights on TFS then check its permissions on server. if he has unnecessary rights on machine level.

Comment: what's your mean about "machine level", would you please give me an example, thanks.